# Asynchronous open source workflow software in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, workflow, pipeline

I have a system that has a bunch of activities (around 40). Each of the activities either call a service or perform some computation. This system has been written in Java. Currently all these activities are executed sequentially and the entire process takes about 2 - 3 seconds. I am trying to optimize the system and try to reduce the latency. I noticed that some of the activities have a data dependence and some of them are independent. I am trying to make these activities run in parallel while also maintaining a sequence for activities that have a data dependence. For example, assume activities 'A' through 'F' are being executed sequentially in this order :

```
A->B->C->D->E->F  (Activities)  
1   2   3   4  5  6  (Time Units)
```

Assume that the data produced by A is used by E and the data produced by B is used by F and the rest of the activities do no depend on any other data. Instead of running these activities sequentially, i should be able to run them parallelly in this order -

```
A->E  
B->F  
C  
D  
1  2 (Time)
```

So instead of 6 time units, the system should be able to complete the entire process in 2 time units. Is there any Open source Java framework that i can use to handle such a workflow         and can seamlessly execute activities once data is available?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the framework exactly for this purpose (Called [Dexecutor](https://github.com/dexecutor)), You can refer [this](https://dzone.com/articles/take-migration-process-to-next-level-using-dexecut) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-dexecutor) Dzone articles for this use case example. For workflow like usecase refer [this](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-examples#2-workflow-example).

Here is how you can do using Dexecutor.

```
DexecutorConfig<String, String> config = new DexecutorConfig<>(executorService, new TaskProvider());
DefaultDexecutor<String, String> executor = new DefaultDexecutor<String, String>(config);

executor.addDependency("A", "E");
executor.addDependency("B", "F");
executor.addIndependent("C");
executor.addIndependent("D");

executor.execute(ExecutionConfig.NON_TERMINATING);
```

Disclaimer : I am the owner of this framework

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on the topology of dependence graph. If it can be split in independent linear sequences, as in your example, then simply represent each sequence as a Runnable and run it each with its own thread or submit them to a thread pool.

If a sequence branches like this:

```
A->B->C
   |
   ->D->E
```

then run sequence ABC first, and run DE from activity B.

Most complex case is when an activity depends on two or more activities:

```
A->B -> |
C  ->   |->D // needs both results from B and C
```

You need a node in the graph which collects results and starts new sequence when all results are collected. If you use threads, then you can represent each dependence as a blocking queue, and let dependent activity first read from all input queues, using `BlockingQueue.take()` method. If you use a thread pool, then you can:

- use Java8 `CompletableFuture` class and its methods `runAfterBoth` (for 2 dependencies) or `allOf` (for arbitrary number of dependencies).
- use some dataflow library (being the author, I recommend https://github.com/rfqu/df4j)
- implement joining node yourself, this is not a big deal

Comment: In my opinion this is difficult to maintain. Workflow engines should be declarative in style rather than imperative.